# Unable to create apply a texture to a line in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

My goal is to create a dashed line using shaders. I've defined a one-dimensional texture, and I think it should be being applied, but all my lines end up black.  I'm hoping there's something simple I'm just missing.

My line vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 iPosition;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main() {
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(iPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My geometry shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(lines) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices=2) out;

out float texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    texCoord = 0.0f;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    texCoord = 1.0f;
    EmitVertex();
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler1D pattern;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
in float texCoord;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture(pattern, texCoord);
}
```

My code:

```
int[] textures = new int[1];
gl4.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
int textureId = textures[0];
gl4.glActiveTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl4.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, textureId);

ByteBuffer pixels = Buffers.newDirectByteBuffer(64 * 4 * 4);
float full = Float.MAX_VALUE;
float empty = 0f;

//opaque red.
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);    

//transparent green.
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);

//opaque red
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);

//transparent green.
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(full);
pixels.putFloat(empty);
pixels.putFloat(empty);

pixels.flip();
gl4.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL4.GL_REPEAT);
gl4.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL4.GL_REPEAT);

gl4.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_NEAREST);
gl4.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_NEAREST);
gl4.glTexImage1D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 4, 32, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_FLOAT, pixels);

  for (MapLayerData mapLayerData : mapLayerDataList) {
     List<Line> lines = mapLayerData.getLines(); 
     for (int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x++){
        Line line = lines.get(x);
        ArrayList<Point2D.Float> points = line.getPoints();

        for (Point2D.Float point : points) {
            vertBuffer.putFloat((float) point.x); 
            vertBuffer.putFloat((float) point.y); 
        }
        vertBuffer.flip();

        int[] bufferPointers = new int[1];
        gl4.glGenBuffers(1, bufferPointers, 0);

        gl4.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferPointers[0]);
        gl4.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (points.size() * 8), vertBuffer, GL.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        gl4.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, 0);
        gl4.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        gl4.glUniformMatrix4fv(lineTransformPointer, 1, false, transform.getMatrix(), 0);
        gl4.glUniform1i(patternPointer, 0);
        gl4.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points.size());

        gl4.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        gl4.glDeleteBuffers(bufferPointers.length, bufferPointers, 0);
        vertBuffer.clear();
     }
  }   
  gl4.glDeleteTextures(1, textures,0);
```

Comment: Where's your `glUniform1i()` call to populate `pattern`?

Comment: I've added a call to glActiveTexture and glUniform1i, but am still not seeing the texture being applied.  I've updated the code above.  Am I missing a call or concept?

Comment: What is the point of your geometry shader? It is totally redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `4` isn't a valid `internalFormat` for `glTexImage1D()` in a Core context.
- There's no evidence you have a VAO bound.  Those are required in a Core context.
- No reason to `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` on a 1D texture.
- No clue what `patternPointer` is.

Comment: Thank you.  Changing my call of glTexImage1D to `gl4.glTexImage1D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, 32, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_BYTE, pixels);` got the texture to display.